# multiselect values, display selected and other data as well

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm using [this jquery effect](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2014/03/jquery-multiselect-dropdown-list-with-checkboxes.html) to multi select days. 
On create everything works fine and now I have partly done and edit action. From controller I'm passing loaded values to the view. Those values represent days of week and I'm passing values to the view those selected week days.

Inside razor view those selected days are received trough

```
@item.DaysSelected
```

and are rendered

```
<select class="selectedDays" multiple="multiple">
    @foreach (var selDay in @item.DaysSelected){
        <option value=@selDay>@selDay</option>
    }
</select>
```

This way I'm able to represent inside jquery multi select plugin selected days but I want to show rest of days as well in order (from mon to sun).

Update:
`@item.DaysSelected` contains List of ints (*previously selected days*) and a `@item.MyDays` contains `List<DayOfWeek>`. I want to render week days in order using jquery multiselect plugin with selected days contained in `@item.DaysSelected`.

How can I achive this?

Thanks

Comment: You may be misunderstanding how to create a dropdown in MVC. If property `DaysSelected` contains an array of the selected days, then you need `@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.DaysSelected, Model.Days)` where property `Days` is a `SelectList` containing all days.

Comment: thanks for a response. Question is updated.